# Pino Transporter and PM2

Tags: node.js, pm2

I want to use [pino-mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pino-mysql) in my Node.js project. How they suggest to use this transporter is using shell piping like:

```
$ node app.js | pino-mysql -c db-configuration.json
```

But in production we use PM2, so my question is how to configure PM2 ecosystem file to integrate pino-mysql and my Node.js application.